# Restful urls. View model specific

Tags: c#, .net, rest, asp.net-web-api, restful-url

I've been going through this [blog](http://blog.2partsmagic.com/restful-uri-design/) and I understand what he is saying, especially regarding the hierarchical structure (walking back along the path).

So

```
/objects/1/property
```

Removing `property` should give you the object with id 1, and removing the id should give you all the objects. Excellent and logical.

But I always expose my data via view models, so,

`/objects/list/1` will give me the object list view model of the object with id 1. Or `/objects/detail/1` will give me the object detail view model for the object with id 1.

Using this approach I have ended up with a long structure just to get a specific view model! I.e. `objects/visualization/analysis/thread`. Is this even restful? What I seem to be doing (subconsciously!) is structuring my restful API to match the namespace or module for where this specific view model lives (so in .NET it will be namespace: app.models.object.visualization.analysis).

How best to structure a restful endpoint like this? Is it better to have something like

`objects-list/1` and `objects-detail/1`?

Thanks.

### Example:

Sorry, I should have been more clear. I will give a .NET example. Suppose I have a cart class

```
public class Cart
{
    public int CardId { get; set; }

    public string CartName { get; set; }

    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<CartItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

With a restful design, I could expose carts as `/carts`, `/carts/1`, `/carts/1/items` and so on. But I always expose view models, not the actual data layer object. I.e.

```
public class CartListModel
{
    public int CartId { get; set; }
    public string CartName { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class CartViewModel
{
    public int CartId { get; set; }
    public string CartName { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<CartItemViewModel> Items { get; set; }
}
```

So this way I am only exposing the data that I actually need for a specific purpose. Now at the moment, I am exposing these view models as such `/carts/list` or `/carts/list/1`. Also `/carts/view` and `/carts/view/1`. So the original question is this restful? Do I infact need a separate endpoint for each view model? So `/carts-list` and `/carts-view`, `carts-view/1` etc.

### Non .NET example

Don't really know what to put here! A view model is a representation of the object, only exposing certain properties necessary to bind to a view.

So suppose my object has the following JSON structure

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Cart 1',
    lastUpdated: '26-Sep-2014 16:51:23',
    items: [
       // an array of objects
    ]
}
```

For a certain view, like a simple table, I may only need the id and the name. So I expose a restful endpoint that gives me back the following structure

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Cart 1'
}
```

Everything else is unnecessary. For a cart edit page, I will probably need a lot more data than just the id and name. The question is, how do I structure a restful endpoint to expose these different representations of the same object?

Comment: What are "the object list view model" and "the object detail view model"? Are they representations of a Resource?

Comment: They are models that only expose certain properties of the object resource (so I suppose they can be treated as different resources?). So the object list view model will only have the id and name of the object, but the object detail view model will have the id and name and whole load of other stuff.

Comment: Could you use easier examples, so anyone without `.NET` experience understands them?

Comment: @Umair What you describe are different *representations* of the same *resource*. The resource is the same and must be identified by the *same* URL. The representations can be selected using content negotiation.

Comment: @Tichodroma, so referring to the example I gave above, would I just do `/cart/1/list` to get the list view model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## URIs are stable

Resources are identified by URIs. The get the object with ID 1, do

```
GET /objects/1
```

To get a list of *all* objects, just

```
GET /objects
```

## Use content negotiation

What *representation* of the object 1 is returned by the server is decided by content negotiation. This is done using HTTP headers, *not* URL path segments or query parameters. Do this:

```
GET /objects/1
Accept: appliction/vnd.com.example.object.detail+json
```

By this the client could request something you call the "detail view model".

If the client wants to get the "list view model", you could do

```
GET /objects/1
Accept: appliction/vnd.com.example.object.list+json
```

**Note**

- The URL is the same for both requests.
- The `Accept` headers have different values.

## *Don't* use different URIs

Don't do any of these:

- `GET /objects/1/list`: This would request the *sub resource* called `list` from object 1.
- `GET /objects/1/list`: This would request another sub resource.
- `GET /objects/1?model=detail` or `GET /objects/1?model=list`: These are *different* URIs which identify *different* resources.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to keep your URL as simple as possible. That means that if your API was a house and you want all clothes of a person named Marie, your URL would be:

```
API/persons/Marie/clothes
```

And not:

```
API/house/persons/Marie/clothes/all
```

Sorry for the bad examples. Rest is pretty hard to explain.

Comment: This is isn't exactly what I want! I don't want to give every single detail of the clothes item. I only for example want to give the designer label in one case, in the other case I may want to give the designer label, date the item was purchased, size, etc.